# I want to load an mp3 from a string path in android?

Tags: android, path, mp3, drawable

I want to load an mp3 from a string path in android which is situated in drawable folder?
Please anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

If you put the file in your assets folder, you can easily access it using `ContextWrapper#getAssets().open(fileName)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you add your mp3 file into android assets folder Url of your file would be `file:///android_asset/yourfile.mp3`